# How do I go to a specific fragment by clicking on something?

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

For example, I have a Navigation Drawer, and I want to be able to navigate straight to a drawer by clicking on items inside it. Here is my code.

```
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //What do I put here??

        }


    });
```

What should I put, such that when the user clicks on something in the Navigation Drawer, the app will jump straight to the selected fragment?

Thanks!

EDIT: I think I managed to solve this, but since my application uses ViewPager to navigate through the fragments, I just use

```
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            viewPager.setCurrentItem(arg2);
                // Close drawer

        }


    });
```

And that works!

Answer (score 1):

Try this code inside OnItemClick:

```
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    // Locate Position
    switch (arg2) {
    case 0:
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, yourFragment1);
        break;
    case 1:
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, yourFragment2);
        break;
    case 2:
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, yourFragment3);
        break;
           // etc add more code if you want//
    }
    /* Commit fragment */
    ft.commit();
    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
    // Close drawer
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
```

Comment: Hmm.. What should I add in the containerViewId parameter? I tried adding the layout where my fragment is inside, but it force closed.

Comment: You should add the FrameLayout in your main activity's XML. If you have something like this `    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>`, that is the one to add in containerViewId param.